# asterisk sip port on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, asterisk

I am working on Ubuntu server 12.04

I have asterisk working. I set the port 5060 as this:

```
     iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -p udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
```

On the client side I have error 408 Registring (Request timeout)

There is no port blocking on the client side.

ON the server side when running

**asterisk -vvvvvr , using set sip debug on**

there is no message that the server is having a request from a client.

What to do? Need some help. Thank you!

In case you ask:
In sip.conf I did specify:

```
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
```

**netstat -plunt**

:

```
...
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4520            0.0.0.0:*                           1002/asterisk   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5060            0.0.0.0:*                           1002/asterisk   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4569            0.0.0.0:*                           1002/asterisk
```

UPDATE:

When checking with   **nmap -v -sU IP -p 5060** and I get:

```
Host is up (0.060s latency).
PORT     STATE         SERVICE
5060/udp open|filtered sip
```

Ouput rules are:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            
 3074  938K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

THE SOLUTION FOR SIP IS THIS:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+firewall+rules

Answer (score -1):

You should add some port:

```
Port 5060 TCP and UDP 
Port 5004 UDP 
Port 10000 UDP (sipgate Stun service - usually 3478/9) 
Ports 16348-32768 UDP (RTP, RTCP multimedia streaming)
```

Your asterisk configuration wrong, refer [here](http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=79474) for more details.

Comment: for media I did add 10000-20000 udp, i also have tcp on 5060

Comment: I 've checked if the port is open using telnet, but i get a connection timed out.

Comment: port 22 is open, but port 5060 seems to be closed though i've set the port to be opened. can u help?

Comment: Check your asterisk configuration.

Comment: THe asterisk configuration are fine, case I ve tested them on my local computer + the sip modules are loaded. I've also checked that.

Comment: when checking with nmap it seems the port is open. :( what should i check now?

Comment: can you help? The asterisk configurations seems to be fine. In fact asterisk worked great till a couple of days when the server hard drive  went down. After it was changed i seem to have issues:|

Comment: It seems client can not receive the packet from server, try add some iptables rule for output packet.

Comment: what rules should I have for output? I've updated my question with the output rules that i currently have on the server side. Please help and thank you!

Comment: THE SIP IS WORKING, but I can't hear anything!!. Why?:( I did set the rtp ports rules on input

Comment: I have this on the server side: dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Unknown)